# Sorting an adjacency matrix in R

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

I currently have an adjacency matrix.

```
example <- data.frame(C=c(0,0,1), A=c(0,0,0), B=c(1,0,0), row.names=c("C","A","B"))

example
  C A B
C 0 0 1
A 0 0 0
B 1 0 0
```

And in the above it correctly indicates that B is adjacent to C and vice-versa.

I want it sorted by row name, so I do the following:

```
example <- example[order(rownames(example)),]
```

The problem is that the corresponding action isn't performed on the columns.

```
example

  C A B
A 0 0 0
B 1 0 0
C 0 0 1
```

So now it incorrectly indicates that B is next to A, and C is next to C.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It might be a clearer example with `example <- data.frame(C=c(0,0,1), A=c(0,0,0), B=c(1,0,0), row.names=c("C","A","B"))`

Comment: Thanks. Edited accordingly

Answer (score 3):

The solution is very simple. After ordering by row, order by column:

```
example <- example[,order(colnames(example))]

> example
  A B C
A 0 0 0
B 0 0 1
C 0 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks to @thelatemail whose comment made me think of the answer

Comment: You could also do it all in step I think - `example[order(rownames(example)),order(colnames(example))]`

Comment: Or with `sort`: `example[sort(rownames(example)), sort(colnames(example))]`.